# How to get the total contributors of the project in Github

Tags: python, github, github-api

I tried use the following python code to get the contributors of the project [rubinius](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius) using api "https://api.github.com/repos/rubinius/rubinius/contributors?page="

The code is:

```
import json, requests
all_contributors = list()
page_count = 1
while True:
    contributors = requests.get("https://api.github.com/repos/rubinius/rubinius/contributors?page=%d"%page_count)
    if contributors != None and contributors.status_code == 200 and len(contributors.json()) > 0:
        all_contributors = all_contributors + contributors.json()
    else:
        break
    page_count = page_count + 1
count=len(all_contributors)
print("-------------------%d" %count)
```

the total contributors is **349**, in the website, the total contributors is **408**, May I know where is problem with my program?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

some contributors are anonymous. so consider setting ?anon=1 parameter
see [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-contributors).

Comment: but if I use ?anon=1, the total is 576, that's why